# show that for any compact set $K \subset X$, there exist an integer $I\geq 1$ such that:

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a banach space.

show that for any compact set $K \subset X,\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $I\geq 1$ and a collection of points $x_1, \dots ,x_I \in X$ such that:

$\sup_{x\in K} \inf_{1 \leq i \leq I} ||x_i - x|| < \epsilon$.

I Know that if $K$ is compact every sequence in $K$ has a convergent sub sequence.  Furthermore a compact space is closed hence complete in $X$ because $X$ is a banach space.

Now I dont understand how to proceed, how do I find a sequence that converges to $x$? And if I do find it, how do I proceed?

Kees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Banach, we need only metric space. The open sets $B_\epsilon(x)=\{\,y\in B\mid d(x,y)<\epsilon\,\}$ are an open cover of $K$. By compactness, there exists a finite subcover.

Comment: so i need to use the topological argument to prove this?